# Unable to get JSON data from an external URL properly

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, highcharts

I am trying to create a Highcharts graph by using a JSON data stored on [an URL](https://www.theice.com/marketdata/DelayedMarkets.shtml?getHistoricalChartDataAsJson=&marketId=5474735&historicalSpan=3)

When I try to get the data from the URL, I failed. But when I copied the data into the script and parse it as if it is a text, I managed to plot the data.

This script works:

```js
var txt = '{"change":"6.039","exchangeImage":"","stripType":"month","contractName":"ICE EUA","exchange":"Europe","settlementPrice":"49.680","bars":[["Tue May 21 00:00:00 2019",25.94],["Wed May 22 00:00:00 2019",26.93],["Thu May 23 00:00:00 2019",26.62],["Fri May 24 00:00:00 2019",26.03],["Mon May 27 00:00:00 2019",26.15],["Tue May 28 00:00:00 2019",26.05],["Wed May 29 00:00:00 2019",26.1],["Thu May 30 00:00:00 2019",25.87],["Fri May 31 00:00:00 2019",25.02],["Mon Jun 03 00:00:00 2019",24.33],["Tue Jun 04 00:00:00 2019",25.16],["Wed Jun 05 00:00:00 2019",24.86],["Thu Jun 06 00:00:00 2019",24.65],["Fri Jun 07 00:00:00 2019",25.22],["Mon Jun 10 00:00:00 2019",25.92],["Tue Jun 11 00:00:00 2019",25.67],["Wed Jun 12 00:00:00 2019",25.48],["Thu Jun 13 00:00:00 2019",25.63],["Fri Jun 14 00:00:00 2019",25.73],["Mon Jun 17 00:00:00 2019",25.72],["Tue Jun 18 00:00:00 2019",25.82],["Wed Jun 19 00:00:00 2019",25.67],["Thu Jun 20 00:00:00 2019",25.81],["Fri Jun 21 00:00:00 2019",26.03],["Mon Jun 24 00:00:00 2019",27.13],["Tue Jun 25 00:00:00 2019",27.21],["Wed Jun 26 00:00:00 2019",28.2],["Thu Jun 27 00:00:00 2019",27.7],["Fri Jun 28 00:00:00 2019",27.05],["Mon Jul 01 00:00:00 2019",27.72],["Tue Jul 02 00:00:00 2019",27.53],["Wed Jul 03 00:00:00 2019",27.33],["Thu Jul 04 00:00:00 2019",26.84],["Fri Jul 05 00:00:00 2019",27.21],["Mon Jul 08 00:00:00 2019",27.67],["Tue Jul 09 00:00:00 2019",27.42],["Wed Jul 10 00:00:00 2019",29.13],["Thu Jul 11 00:00:00 2019",29.19],["Fri Jul 12 00:00:00 2019",29.71],["Mon Jul 15 00:00:00 2019",29.99],["Tue Jul 16 00:00:00 2019",29.42],["Wed Jul 17 00:00:00 2019",29.42],["Thu Jul 18 00:00:00 2019",28.71],["Fri Jul 19 00:00:00 2019",29.85],["Mon Jul 22 00:00:00 2019",29.95],["Tue Jul 23 00:00:00 2019",30.76],["Wed Jul 24 00:00:00 2019",30.13],["Thu Jul 25 00:00:00 2019",29.94],["Fri Jul 26 00:00:00 2019",29.2],["Mon Jul 29 00:00:00 2019",29.3],["Tue Jul 30 00:00:00 2019",28.76],["Wed Jul 31 00:00:00 2019",28.84],["Thu Aug 01 00:00:00 2019",30.29],["Fri Aug 02 00:00:00 2019",30.08],["Mon Aug 05 00:00:00 2019",29.51],["Tue Aug 06 00:00:00 2019",29.19],["Wed Aug 07 00:00:00 2019",29.04],["Thu Aug 08 00:00:00 2019",29.28],["Fri Aug 09 00:00:00 2019",28.87],["Mon Aug 12 00:00:00 2019",27.43],["Tue Aug 13 00:00:00 2019",27.83],["Wed Aug 14 00:00:00 2019",27.65],["Thu Aug 15 00:00:00 2019",26.72],["Fri Aug 16 00:00:00 2019",26.67],["Mon Aug 19 00:00:00 2019",27.28],["Tue Aug 20 00:00:00 2019",26.97],["Wed Aug 21 00:00:00 2019",26.72],["Thu Aug 22 00:00:00 2019",26.36],["Fri Aug 23 00:00:00 2019",25.79],["Mon Aug 26 00:00:00 2019",26.52],["Tue Aug 27 00:00:00 2019",26.08],["Wed Aug 28 00:00:00 2019",26.66],["Thu Aug 29 00:00:00 2019",27.12],["Fri Aug 30 00:00:00 2019",26.95],["Mon Sep 02 00:00:00 2019",25.8],["Tue Sep 03 00:00:00 2019",25.83],["Wed Sep 04 00:00:00 2019",26.1],["Thu Sep 05 00:00:00 2019",26.11],["Fri Sep 06 00:00:00 2019",25.67],["Mon Sep 09 00:00:00 2019",25.6],["Tue Sep 10 00:00:00 2019",27.31],["Wed Sep 11 00:00:00 2019",26.88],["Thu Sep 12 00:00:00 2019",27.04],["Fri Sep 13 00:00:00 2019",27],["Mon Sep 16 00:00:00 2019",27.68],["Tue Sep 17 00:00:00 2019",26.85],["Wed Sep 18 00:00:00 2019",26.07],["Thu Sep 19 00:00:00 2019",26.58],["Fri Sep 20 00:00:00 2019",27.18],["Mon Sep 23 00:00:00 2019",26.43],["Tue Sep 24 00:00:00 2019",26.17],["Wed Sep 25 00:00:00 2019",25.86],["Thu Sep 26 00:00:00 2019",26.29],["Fri Sep 27 00:00:00 2019",25.94],["Mon Sep 30 00:00:00 2019",25.36],["Tue Oct 01 00:00:00 2019",25.65],["Wed Oct 02 00:00:00 2019",24.8],["Thu Oct 03 00:00:00 2019",23.8],["Fri Oct 04 00:00:00 2019",23.53],["Mon Oct 07 00:00:00 2019",23.98],["Tue Oct 08 00:00:00 2019",23.12],["Wed Oct 09 00:00:00 2019",23.21],["Thu Oct 10 00:00:00 2019",23.8],["Fri Oct 11 00:00:00 2019",24.98],["Mon Oct 14 00:00:00 2019",24.69],["Tue Oct 15 00:00:00 2019",26.27],["Wed Oct 16 00:00:00 2019",26.86],["Thu Oct 17 00:00:00 2019",26.62],["Fri Oct 18 00:00:00 2019",26.43],["Mon Oct 21 00:00:00 2019",26.46],["Tue Oct 22 00:00:00 2019",26.17],["Wed Oct 23 00:00:00 2019",25.25],["Thu Oct 24 00:00:00 2019",25.94],["Fri Oct 25 00:00:00 2019",25.46],["Mon Oct 28 00:00:00 2019",25.59],["Tue Oct 29 00:00:00 2019",25.91],["Wed Oct 30 00:00:00 2019",26.43],["Thu Oct 31 00:00:00 2019",26.03],["Fri Nov 01 00:00:00 2019",25.7],["Mon Nov 04 00:00:00 2019",26.03],["Tue Nov 05 00:00:00 2019",25.91],["Wed Nov 06 00:00:00 2019",25.19],["Thu Nov 07 00:00:00 2019",25.33],["Fri Nov 08 00:00:00 2019",25.23],["Mon Nov 11 00:00:00 2019",25.31],["Tue Nov 12 00:00:00 2019",24.49],["Wed Nov 13 00:00:00 2019",24.76],["Thu Nov 14 00:00:00 2019",24.33],["Fri Nov 15 00:00:00 2019",24.23],["Mon Nov 18 00:00:00 2019",23.79],["Tue Nov 19 00:00:00 2019",23.83],["Wed Nov 20 00:00:00 2019",24.41],["Thu Nov 21 00:00:00 2019",24.32],["Fri Nov 22 00:00:00 2019",24.97],["Mon Nov 25 00:00:00 2019",24.83],["Tue Nov 26 00:00:00 2019",24.78],["Wed Nov 27 00:00:00 2019",25.51],["Thu Nov 28 00:00:00 2019",25.4],["Fri Nov 29 00:00:00 2019",25.61],["Mon Dec 02 00:00:00 2019",24.72],["Tue Dec 03 00:00:00 2019",24.4],["Wed Dec 04 00:00:00 2019",25.14],["Thu Dec 05 00:00:00 2019",25.09],["Fri Dec 06 00:00:00 2019",25.34],["Mon Dec 09 00:00:00 2019",25.53],["Tue Dec 10 00:00:00 2019",25.34],["Wed Dec 11 00:00:00 2019",24.86],["Thu Dec 12 00:00:00 2019",25.46],["Fri Dec 13 00:00:00 2019",24.38],["Mon Dec 16 00:00:00 2019",25.2],["Tue Dec 17 00:00:00 2019",26.29],["Wed Dec 18 00:00:00 2019",26.81],["Thu Dec 19 00:00:00 2019",27.06],["Fri Dec 20 00:00:00 2019",26.89],["Mon Dec 23 00:00:00 2019",26.76],["Tue Dec 24 00:00:00 2019",26.3],["Thu Dec 26 00:00:00 2019",26.3],["Fri Dec 27 00:00:00 2019",26.93],["Mon Dec 30 00:00:00 2019",25.31],["Tue Dec 31 00:00:00 2019",24.86],["Thu Jan 02 00:00:00 2020",24.58],["Fri Jan 03 00:00:00 2020",25.18],["Mon Jan 06 00:00:00 2020",24.43],["Tue Jan 07 00:00:00 2020",24.75],["Wed Jan 08 00:00:00 2020",24.28],["Thu Jan 09 00:00:00 2020",24.88],["Fri Jan 10 00:00:00 2020",24.42],["Mon Jan 13 00:00:00 2020",24.35],["Tue Jan 14 00:00:00 2020",24.06],["Wed Jan 15 00:00:00 2020",24.73],["Thu Jan 16 00:00:00 2020",25.06],["Fri Jan 17 00:00:00 2020",25.66],["Mon Jan 20 00:00:00 2020",25.38],["Tue Jan 21 00:00:00 2020",25.13],["Wed Jan 22 00:00:00 2020",25.22],["Thu Jan 23 00:00:00 2020",24.9],["Fri Jan 24 00:00:00 2020",24.57],["Mon Jan 27 00:00:00 2020",24.77],["Tue Jan 28 00:00:00 2020",24.82],["Wed Jan 29 00:00:00 2020",24.17],["Thu Jan 30 00:00:00 2020",23.91],["Fri Jan 31 00:00:00 2020",24.06],["Mon Feb 03 00:00:00 2020",23.39],["Tue Feb 04 00:00:00 2020",23.54],["Wed Feb 05 00:00:00 2020",23.95],["Thu Feb 06 00:00:00 2020",23.74],["Fri Feb 07 00:00:00 2020",23.51],["Mon Feb 10 00:00:00 2020",23.34],["Tue Feb 11 00:00:00 2020",23.5],["Wed Feb 12 00:00:00 2020",24.07],["Thu Feb 13 00:00:00 2020",24.59],["Fri Feb 14 00:00:00 2020",24.48],["Mon Feb 17 00:00:00 2020",25.24],["Tue Feb 18 00:00:00 2020",25.33],["Wed Feb 19 00:00:00 2020",25.9],["Thu Feb 20 00:00:00 2020",25.83],["Fri Feb 21 00:00:00 2020",25.8],["Mon Feb 24 00:00:00 2020",24.77],["Tue Feb 25 00:00:00 2020",24.38],["Wed Feb 26 00:00:00 2020",24.45],["Thu Feb 27 00:00:00 2020",23.78],["Fri Feb 28 00:00:00 2020",23.8],["Mon Mar 02 00:00:00 2020",23.71],["Tue Mar 03 00:00:00 2020",23.55],["Wed Mar 04 00:00:00 2020",24.02],["Thu Mar 05 00:00:00 2020",23.99],["Fri Mar 06 00:00:00 2020",23.6],["Mon Mar 09 00:00:00 2020",23.46],["Tue Mar 10 00:00:00 2020",24.28],["Wed Mar 11 00:00:00 2020",24.1],["Thu Mar 12 00:00:00 2020",22.72],["Fri Mar 13 00:00:00 2020",22.14],["Mon Mar 16 00:00:00 2020",19.72],["Tue Mar 17 00:00:00 2020",18.69],["Wed Mar 18 00:00:00 2020",15.71],["Thu Mar 19 00:00:00 2020",16.76],["Fri Mar 20 00:00:00 2020",16.44],["Mon Mar 23 00:00:00 2020",15.88],["Tue Mar 24 00:00:00 2020",17.11],["Wed Mar 25 00:00:00 2020",17.86],["Thu Mar 26 00:00:00 2020",17.7],["Fri Mar 27 00:00:00 2020",16.74],["Mon Mar 30 00:00:00 2020",17.41],["Tue Mar 31 00:00:00 2020",18.03],["Wed Apr 01 00:00:00 2020",17.43],["Thu Apr 02 00:00:00 2020",18.42],["Fri Apr 03 00:00:00 2020",18.33],["Mon Apr 06 00:00:00 2020",20.77],["Tue Apr 07 00:00:00 2020",20.89],["Wed Apr 08 00:00:00 2020",21.53],["Thu Apr 09 00:00:00 2020",21.46],["Mon Apr 13 00:00:00 2020",21.46],["Tue Apr 14 00:00:00 2020",20.18],["Wed Apr 15 00:00:00 2020",19.64],["Thu Apr 16 00:00:00 2020",21.31],["Fri Apr 17 00:00:00 2020",22.08],["Mon Apr 20 00:00:00 2020",21.76],["Tue Apr 21 00:00:00 2020",20.23],["Wed Apr 22 00:00:00 2020",21.04],["Thu Apr 23 00:00:00 2020",21.41],["Fri Apr 24 00:00:00 2020",21.12],["Mon Apr 27 00:00:00 2020",20.66],["Tue Apr 28 00:00:00 2020",20.59],["Wed Apr 29 00:00:00 2020",20.57],["Thu Apr 30 00:00:00 2020",19.94],["Fri May 01 00:00:00 2020",19.34],["Mon May 04 00:00:00 2020",19.72],["Tue May 05 00:00:00 2020",19.46],["Wed May 06 00:00:00 2020",19.38],["Thu May 07 00:00:00 2020",19.91],["Fri May 08 00:00:00 2020",19.73],["Mon May 11 00:00:00 2020",19.44],["Tue May 12 00:00:00 2020",18.89],["Wed May 13 00:00:00 2020",19.04],["Thu May 14 00:00:00 2020",19.2],["Fri May 15 00:00:00 2020",19.54],["Mon May 18 00:00:00 2020",20.71],["Tue May 19 00:00:00 2020",20.33],["Wed May 20 00:00:00 2020",21.63],["Thu May 21 00:00:00 2020",21.55],["Fri May 22 00:00:00 2020",21.77],["Mon May 25 00:00:00 2020",21.96],["Tue May 26 00:00:00 2020",21.97],["Wed May 27 00:00:00 2020",21.7],["Thu May 28 00:00:00 2020",21.62],["Fri May 29 00:00:00 2020",21.76],["Mon Jun 01 00:00:00 2020",21.33],["Tue Jun 02 00:00:00 2020",22.42],["Wed Jun 03 00:00:00 2020",22.43],["Thu Jun 04 00:00:00 2020",22.56],["Fri Jun 05 00:00:00 2020",23.59],["Mon Jun 08 00:00:00 2020",23.05],["Tue Jun 09 00:00:00 2020",22.82],["Wed Jun 10 00:00:00 2020",23.25],["Thu Jun 11 00:00:00 2020",22.61],["Fri Jun 12 00:00:00 2020",22.35],["Mon Jun 15 00:00:00 2020",22.51],["Tue Jun 16 00:00:00 2020",23.13],["Wed Jun 17 00:00:00 2020",23.1],["Thu Jun 18 00:00:00 2020",24.8],["Fri Jun 19 00:00:00 2020",24.49],["Mon Jun 22 00:00:00 2020",24.86],["Tue Jun 23 00:00:00 2020",25.73],["Wed Jun 24 00:00:00 2020",25.72],["Thu Jun 25 00:00:00 2020",25.5],["Fri Jun 26 00:00:00 2020",25.05],["Mon Jun 29 00:00:00 2020",26.94],["Tue Jun 30 00:00:00 2020",27.27],["Wed Jul 01 00:00:00 2020",28.01],["Thu Jul 02 00:00:00 2020",27.66],["Fri Jul 03 00:00:00 2020",28.21],["Mon Jul 06 00:00:00 2020",30.01],["Tue Jul 07 00:00:00 2020",29.7],["Wed Jul 08 00:00:00 2020",29.63],["Thu Jul 09 00:00:00 2020",28.92],["Fri Jul 10 00:00:00 2020",29.34],["Mon Jul 13 00:00:00 2020",29.68],["Tue Jul 14 00:00:00 2020",30],["Wed Jul 15 00:00:00 2020",29.21],["Thu Jul 16 00:00:00 2020",27.08],["Fri Jul 17 00:00:00 2020",28.22],["Mon Jul 20 00:00:00 2020",26.58],["Tue Jul 21 00:00:00 2020",26.99],["Wed Jul 22 00:00:00 2020",27.01],["Thu Jul 23 00:00:00 2020",27.71],["Fri Jul 24 00:00:00 2020",26.75],["Mon Jul 27 00:00:00 2020",25.38],["Tue Jul 28 00:00:00 2020",26.11],["Wed Jul 29 00:00:00 2020",26.55],["Thu Jul 30 00:00:00 2020",25.9],["Fri Jul 31 00:00:00 2020",26.64],["Mon Aug 03 00:00:00 2020",26.48],["Tue Aug 04 00:00:00 2020",27.17],["Wed Aug 05 00:00:00 2020",27.11],["Thu Aug 06 00:00:00 2020",26.74],["Fri Aug 07 00:00:00 2020",26.77],["Mon Aug 10 00:00:00 2020",27.05],["Tue Aug 11 00:00:00 2020",26.53],["Wed Aug 12 00:00:00 2020",26.32],["Thu Aug 13 00:00:00 2020",25.78],["Fri Aug 14 00:00:00 2020",25.83],["Mon Aug 17 00:00:00 2020",26.64],["Tue Aug 18 00:00:00 2020",26.89],["Wed Aug 19 00:00:00 2020",26.57],["Thu Aug 20 00:00:00 2020",26.24],["Fri Aug 21 00:00:00 2020",25.98],["Mon Aug 24 00:00:00 2020",27.82],["Tue Aug 25 00:00:00 2020",28.96],["Wed Aug 26 00:00:00 2020",28.97],["Thu Aug 27 00:00:00 2020",28.73],["Fri Aug 28 00:00:00 2020",29.88],["Mon Aug 31 00:00:00 2020",29.02],["Tue Sep 01 00:00:00 2020",28.1],["Wed Sep 02 00:00:00 2020",28.58],["Thu Sep 03 00:00:00 2020",29.08],["Fri Sep 04 00:00:00 2020",27.7],["Mon Sep 07 00:00:00 2020",27.39],["Tue Sep 08 00:00:00 2020",27.13],["Wed Sep 09 00:00:00 2020",27.52],["Thu Sep 10 00:00:00 2020",28.73],["Fri Sep 11 00:00:00 2020",28.56],["Mon Sep 14 00:00:00 2020",30.77],["Tue Sep 15 00:00:00 2020",30.1],["Wed Sep 16 00:00:00 2020",30.28],["Thu Sep 17 00:00:00 2020",28.72],["Fri Sep 18 00:00:00 2020",28.27],["Mon Sep 21 00:00:00 2020",26.66],["Tue Sep 22 00:00:00 2020",28.08],["Wed Sep 23 00:00:00 2020",26.73],["Thu Sep 24 00:00:00 2020",27.01],["Fri Sep 25 00:00:00 2020",26.38],["Mon Sep 28 00:00:00 2020",27.92],["Tue Sep 29 00:00:00 2020",27],["Wed Sep 30 00:00:00 2020",27.14],["Thu Oct 01 00:00:00 2020",26.72],["Fri Oct 02 00:00:00 2020",27.24],["Mon Oct 05 00:00:00 2020",27.15],["Tue Oct 06 00:00:00 2020",27],["Wed Oct 07 00:00:00 2020",27.1],["Thu Oct 08 00:00:00 2020",26.54],["Fri Oct 09 00:00:00 2020",25.91],["Mon Oct 12 00:00:00 2020",26.07],["Tue Oct 13 00:00:00 2020",25.41],["Wed Oct 14 00:00:00 2020",25.94],["Thu Oct 15 00:00:00 2020",25.16],["Fri Oct 16 00:00:00 2020",25.07],["Mon Oct 19 00:00:00 2020",25.17],["Tue Oct 20 00:00:00 2020",24.6],["Wed Oct 21 00:00:00 2020",23.76],["Thu Oct 22 00:00:00 2020",24.37],["Fri Oct 23 00:00:00 2020",25.67],["Mon Oct 26 00:00:00 2020",24.04],["Tue Oct 27 00:00:00 2020",24.24],["Wed Oct 28 00:00:00 2020",23.21],["Thu Oct 29 00:00:00 2020",23.84],["Fri Oct 30 00:00:00 2020",23.88],["Mon Nov 02 00:00:00 2020",23.84],["Tue Nov 03 00:00:00 2020",24.55],["Wed Nov 04 00:00:00 2020",25.27],["Thu Nov 05 00:00:00 2020",26.14],["Fri Nov 06 00:00:00 2020",25.56],["Mon Nov 09 00:00:00 2020",26.69],["Tue Nov 10 00:00:00 2020",26.37],["Wed Nov 11 00:00:00 2020",26.26],["Thu Nov 12 00:00:00 2020",26.05],["Fri Nov 13 00:00:00 2020",26.41],["Mon Nov 16 00:00:00 2020",27.52],["Tue Nov 17 00:00:00 2020",26.77],["Wed Nov 18 00:00:00 2020",27.33],["Thu Nov 19 00:00:00 2020",26.49],["Fri Nov 20 00:00:00 2020",26.89],["Mon Nov 23 00:00:00 2020",27.41],["Tue Nov 24 00:00:00 2020",27.79],["Wed Nov 25 00:00:00 2020",27.79],["Thu Nov 26 00:00:00 2020",28.29],["Fri Nov 27 00:00:00 2020",28.33],["Mon Nov 30 00:00:00 2020",29.34],["Tue Dec 01 00:00:00 2020",29.07],["Wed Dec 02 00:00:00 2020",29.75],["Thu Dec 03 00:00:00 2020",29.2],["Fri Dec 04 00:00:00 2020",30.31],["Mon Dec 07 00:00:00 2020",29.82],["Tue Dec 08 00:00:00 2020",29.77],["Wed Dec 09 00:00:00 2020",29.91],["Thu Dec 10 00:00:00 2020",31.12],["Fri Dec 11 00:00:00 2020",30.73],["Mon Dec 14 00:00:00 2020",31.01],["Tue Dec 15 00:00:00 2020",32.18],["Wed Dec 16 00:00:00 2020",31.78],["Thu Dec 17 00:00:00 2020",31.96],["Fri Dec 18 00:00:00 2020",31.1],["Mon Dec 21 00:00:00 2020",30.89],["Tue Dec 22 00:00:00 2020",31.15],["Wed Dec 23 00:00:00 2020",31.92],["Thu Dec 24 00:00:00 2020",32.19],["Mon Dec 28 00:00:00 2020",33.44],["Tue Dec 29 00:00:00 2020",33.02],["Wed Dec 30 00:00:00 2020",32.19],["Thu Dec 31 00:00:00 2020",32.72],["Mon Jan 04 00:00:00 2021",33.69],["Tue Jan 05 00:00:00 2021",32.96],["Wed Jan 06 00:00:00 2021",33.63],["Thu Jan 07 00:00:00 2021",34.76],["Fri Jan 08 00:00:00 2021",34.92],["Mon Jan 11 00:00:00 2021",34.53],["Tue Jan 12 00:00:00 2021",34.66],["Wed Jan 13 00:00:00 2021",33.65],["Thu Jan 14 00:00:00 2021",33.53],["Fri Jan 15 00:00:00 2021",31.74],["Mon Jan 18 00:00:00 2021",31.62],["Tue Jan 19 00:00:00 2021",33.09],["Wed Jan 20 00:00:00 2021",32.91],["Thu Jan 21 00:00:00 2021",34.11],["Fri Jan 22 00:00:00 2021",34.24],["Mon Jan 25 00:00:00 2021",33.16],["Tue Jan 26 00:00:00 2021",33.35],["Wed Jan 27 00:00:00 2021",33.28],["Thu Jan 28 00:00:00 2021",33.95],["Fri Jan 29 00:00:00 2021",32.95],["Mon Feb 01 00:00:00 2021",32.85],["Tue Feb 02 00:00:00 2021",34.97],["Wed Feb 03 00:00:00 2021",37.43],["Thu Feb 04 00:00:00 2021",37.27],["Fri Feb 05 00:00:00 2021",38.2],["Mon Feb 08 00:00:00 2021",38.61],["Tue Feb 09 00:00:00 2021",38.26],["Wed Feb 10 00:00:00 2021",39.33],["Thu Feb 11 00:00:00 2021",38.76],["Fri Feb 12 00:00:00 2021",40.02],["Mon Feb 15 00:00:00 2021",39.52],["Tue Feb 16 00:00:00 2021",38.86],["Wed Feb 17 00:00:00 2021",38.09],["Thu Feb 18 00:00:00 2021",38.32],["Fri Feb 19 00:00:00 2021",37.4],["Mon Feb 22 00:00:00 2021",37.96],["Tue Feb 23 00:00:00 2021",38.67],["Wed Feb 24 00:00:00 2021",39.15],["Thu Feb 25 00:00:00 2021",38.26],["Fri Feb 26 00:00:00 2021",37.28],["Mon Mar 01 00:00:00 2021",37.13],["Tue Mar 02 00:00:00 2021",38.35],["Wed Mar 03 00:00:00 2021",37.47],["Thu Mar 04 00:00:00 2021",38.16],["Fri Mar 05 00:00:00 2021",39.02],["Mon Mar 08 00:00:00 2021",39.13],["Tue Mar 09 00:00:00 2021",40.65],["Wed Mar 10 00:00:00 2021",41.54],["Thu Mar 11 00:00:00 2021",41.93],["Fri Mar 12 00:00:00 2021",42.85],["Mon Mar 15 00:00:00 2021",42.39],["Tue Mar 16 00:00:00 2021",41.6],["Wed Mar 17 00:00:00 2021",42.99],["Thu Mar 18 00:00:00 2021",42.4],["Fri Mar 19 00:00:00 2021",41.97],["Mon Mar 22 00:00:00 2021",42.84],["Tue Mar 23 00:00:00 2021",41.43],["Wed Mar 24 00:00:00 2021",41.6],["Thu Mar 25 00:00:00 2021",40.35],["Fri Mar 26 00:00:00 2021",41.73],["Mon Mar 29 00:00:00 2021",41.85],["Tue Mar 30 00:00:00 2021",42.05],["Wed Mar 31 00:00:00 2021",42.55],["Thu Apr 01 00:00:00 2021",42.47],["Mon Apr 05 00:00:00 2021",42.47],["Tue Apr 06 00:00:00 2021",44.24],["Wed Apr 07 00:00:00 2021",43.86],["Thu Apr 08 00:00:00 2021",43.48],["Fri Apr 09 00:00:00 2021",43.64],["Mon Apr 12 00:00:00 2021",44.48],["Tue Apr 13 00:00:00 2021",43.85],["Wed Apr 14 00:00:00 2021",43.82],["Thu Apr 15 00:00:00 2021",44.16],["Fri Apr 16 00:00:00 2021",44.42],["Mon Apr 19 00:00:00 2021",44.35],["Tue Apr 20 00:00:00 2021",44.89],["Wed Apr 21 00:00:00 2021",45.91],["Thu Apr 22 00:00:00 2021",47.09],["Fri Apr 23 00:00:00 2021",46.95],["Mon Apr 26 00:00:00 2021",47.2],["Tue Apr 27 00:00:00 2021",47.3],["Wed Apr 28 00:00:00 2021",47.79],["Thu Apr 29 00:00:00 2021",48.02],["Fri Apr 30 00:00:00 2021",48.84],["Mon May 03 00:00:00 2021",49.42],["Tue May 04 00:00:00 2021",48.61],["Wed May 05 00:00:00 2021",49.45],["Thu May 06 00:00:00 2021",49.94],["Fri May 07 00:00:00 2021",50.45],["Mon May 10 00:00:00 2021",52.22],["Tue May 11 00:00:00 2021",53.04],["Wed May 12 00:00:00 2021",55.32],["Thu May 13 00:00:00 2021",54.49],["Fri May 14 00:00:00 2021",56.65],["Mon May 17 00:00:00 2021",56.34],["Tue May 18 00:00:00 2021",53.07],["Wed May 19 00:00:00 2021",49.68]],"percentChangeDirection":"up","marketId":5474735,"stripDescription":"Dec21","lastPrice":"52.680"}'
var obj = JSON.parse(txt);


var series = [{
    data: []
}];

for (var i = 0, l = obj.bars.length; i < l; i++) {
    
    series[0].data[i] = [obj.bars[i][0], obj.bars[i][1]];
}


var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
    chart: {
        renderTo: 'container'
    },
    xAxis: {
        type: 'datetime'
    },
    series: series
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>
<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

This doesn't work:

```js
var series = [{
  data: []
}];

var url = 'https://www.theice.com/marketdata/DelayedMarkets.shtml?getHistoricalChartDataAsJson=&marketId=5474735&historicalSpan=3'

$.getJSON(url, function(data) {
  for (var i = 0, l = data.bars.length; i < l; i++) {
    series[0].data[i] = [data.bars[i][0], data.bars[i][1]];
  }
});

var chart = new Highcharts.Chart({
  chart: {
    renderTo: 'container'
  },
  xAxis: {
    type: 'datetime'
  },
  series: series
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/highstock.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/data.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/exporting.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/stock/modules/export-data.js"></script>

<div id="container" style="height: 400px; min-width: 310px"></div>
```

Comment: Move the code that creates the chart into the callback function.

Comment: I got a CORS error when I tried the snippet. If that is the case, take a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-receive-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-i

Comment: Even if the SO Question referenced in the "closed" banner is a problem the user is facing, it's probably not the only one. As Kinglish stated, CORS are also a big problem with this code. Even if done correctly, it wouldn't work because of those limitation

Comment: @Drago96 I didn't understand anything from the recommended posts

Comment: The problem intended was that, in the code you posted, the "series" variable, ideally initialized inside the getJSON callback, was used outside of the callback itself. When using asynchronous operation, you should keep all reference to the received data inside of the callback. In your case, this means moving the "var chart = ..." command inside the getJSON callback

Comment: @Drago96 Ah I meant the other posts. Yeah I had tried that one too, but failed again. As far as I understood, the website restricts access. Alternatively I tried a Python web app, failed to connect again. It makes sense because it is an exchange website^^. But thanks for your answer.

Comment: Yeah, sadly when CORS is implicated, it is almost always impossible to solve the problem without adding a specific header to the response from the APIs. CORS was invented to prevent attacks, and it work really well, but sometimes it does prevent even "normal" usage of those resources. P.S. CORS stands for Cross-Origin Resource Sharing :)